# Multibinding using TemplatedParent always returns 0.0 for ActualHeight

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm attempting to use Multibinding in a ControlTemplate to draw some Lines. My XAML:

```
                <Line X1="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Y1="0"
                      X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Line.Y2>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource XAMLResourceAddConverter}">
                            <Binding Source="-15"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Line.Y2>
                </Line>
```

And my convertor:

```
public class AddConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int result =
            Int32.Parse(values[0].ToString()) + Int32.Parse(values[1].ToString());
        return result;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

The Line is not actually drawing. Stepping through the Convertor, I found that the `value[1]` (which should be the ActualHeight) is always coming through as 0.0. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindAncestor` in this case as `TemplatedParent` is not being resolved in binding

```
<Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyType}}"></Binding>
```

secondly as you are using a hardcoded value `-15` for first binding in the multibinding, perhaps you can bind the Y2 inline using converter parameter

so if you can change the converter `XAMLResourceAddConverter` to a `IValueConveter` then perhaps you can use it as

```
Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource XAMLResourceAddConverter}, ConverterParameter=-15}"
```